# Necesito obtener el resultado de un SELECT y guardarlo en una variable Mysqli PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Necesito capturar el resultado de un `select` y guardarlo en una variable, con el fin de realizar un `while`,

Es para un sistema de inscripción de cursos en PHP, en donde el usuario se inscriba a uno de los cursos disponibles y poder consultar si el curso cuenta con vacantes,

La tabla se llama "cursos" y es así,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM `cursos` where `vacantes` >0 and `id_curso`='$id_curso'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);

 while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
      $cant_vacantes = $registro['vacantes'];
        }


if ($cant_vacantes==null){ 
  echo"<Script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
      alert('!Los cupos de este curso se han acabado!')
      window.location.href='#';
       </Script>";

 }else{

... }
```

La idea es que, después del `else`, pueda hacer la inserción de datos y el `update` del campo vacantes, ademas de enviar el correo de confirmar (todo esto ya resuelto).

Sin embargo, al arrancarlo en localhost, me aparece el siguiente error:

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\capacitacion\cursos\envia_mail_2019.php on line 86

¿Cual puede ser el problema?,

De antemano, mil gracias

Comment: No tiene que ver con la pregunta pero, me parece un poco mucho int(50) para las vacantes e int(100) para el ambito -lo que sea que signifique-. Si la intención es que abarque 50 lugares (vacantes) con int(2) es suficiente. int(3) para 100 ambitos.

Comment: Cuál es el problema que estás encontrando?

Comment: Disculpa estimado, se me olvido agregar el problema en sí, post editado

Comment: Posiblemente indica un error en tu query, te devuelve falso y por eso dice que el resultado es booleano. Comprueba como printa la query, quita las comillas de nombre de tabla y nombres de campos, y también puedes printar mysqli_error para ver qué error da. Por otro lado, como comenta Juan, un int(50) o un int(100) no tienen sentido, int admite 4bytes te dejo un enlace dónde puedes ver los valores máximos https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.0-en/integer-types.html

Comment: Gracias carmen pero probe sin comillas y aparece el mismo error, la query esta bien la probe en el phpmyadmin:

SELECT * FROM cursos where vacantes >0 and id_curso=$id_curso

Cambie el $id_curso por cualquier otro valor (1) y cero problemas, pero en el php tengo el mismo error:

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\capacitacion\cursos\envia_mail_2019.php on line 87

Comment: Prueba con mysqli_error para ver si te da más información del error, te dejo un enlace de ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/a/15440076/5675636